# DirectX 11 SDK Examples have a Black Border when going fullscreen

Tags: c++, sdk, directx

I'm using an *ATI Radeon HD5870* GPU, and I have a annoying black border problem when going full-screen in my DirectX 11 C++ application. I also have this problem when building all of the DirectX 11 SDK examples. I have the latest graphics drivers, and I do not experience this problem in recent retail games (such as Far Cry 3).

Do I need to add ATI's libraries to my Visual Studio project? It seems like a driver issue.
My mouse does not pass these black borders either, so the graphics card is literally limited to the center of the screen with a black border surrounding it.

Using: 
c++ @ Visual studio 2010
DXUT 
Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Do you have the exact same borders on every full-screen resolution you try, or only on particular resolutions?

Comment: Is your display connected via HDMI? ATI defaults to 15% overscan over HDMI, even if the connected display doesn't need it. You should be able to fix the problem in Catalyst Control Center. Not sure why it doesn't show up in retail games though.